# .htaccess RewriteRule plus httpd.conf ScriptAliasMatch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been adding 301 redirects successfully into our site .htaccess file, so that I can point url's from our old site to the correct url's on our new site, however I cannot get any redirects to work where the old url contains a ".pgm".

The ".pgm's" are RPG programs on our IBM iSeries server, and the url's on the new site are redirected in the httpd.conf file as follows:

```
ScriptAliasMatch (.*)\.pgm$ /QSYS.LIB/B2CRLIVE.LIB/$1.pgm
```

All of the url redirects for both vanity links and for url's from the old site are done in .htaccess, and these work fine, unless the old url contains ".pgm", in which case no matter what I try to do I end up with a 404 page.

An example of the old site url is:

```
http://mydomain/b2c/b2chome.pgm
```

The redirect I am using is:

```
RewriteRule b2chome /category/0/Product\ Range [R=301,L]
```

This works fine if the url is:

```
http://mydomain/b2c/b2chome
```

but once you add ".pgm" to any url it just results in a 404 page.

The ScriptAliasMatch works for pointing ".pgm's" to the correct program library, but the programs used on the old site don't exist in the library which is being pointed at. I don't think this is the problem though, because I think if it was I would get a script error of some kind.

Any ideas please?

Comment: I do not know if it's me and my particular English, but I do not understand. You redirect (try to) `http://mydomain/b2c/b2chome.pgm` -> `http://mydomain/category/0/Product Range` and after ?

Comment: The result of this redirect is that the original url remains and the 404 page is displayed. If the url did not contain a .pgm the redirect would work, but for some reason the rewrite is not having any effect on url's that contain ".pgm".  Hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: On the old site: With the `RewriteRule b2chome /category/0/Product\ Range [R=301,L]`. When you use `http://mydomain/b2c/b2chome.pgm` it's an external redirection to `http://mydomain/category/0/Product Range`...

Comment: But I don't understand why http://mydomain/b2c/b2chome will redirect ok but http://mydomain/b2c/b2chome.pgm will not. Unfortunately many of the pages on the old site end in .pgm.

Comment: I was wondering if I changed the ScriptAliasMatch to only work on new url's of the form "mydomain.com/script.pgm" and not on the old url's of the form "mydomain.com/b2c/script.pgm" if this would work? Unfortunately changing the httpd.conf file means taking the production server down to test.

Comment: You have to start at the beginning ... You redirect to `http://mydomain/category/0/Product Range`. You have to watch what happens from this link...

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution, albeit not the one I was looking for. I added a redirect into the httpd.conf file, above the ScriptAliasMatch as follows:

```
Redirect 301 /b2c/b2chome.pgm http://www.domain.com/category.pgm
```

This at least works, even though I can now only place the non-pgm redirects in the .htaccess file. The .pgm redirects are at least limited in number, whereas I keep finding non-pgm links from the old site that are being referenced from somewhere, often old links on forums.